# How I can convert SVG paths elements to glyph element in SVG fonts using Java?

Tags: java, xml, svg, fonts

I need to convert list of paths from SVG file like below:

```
<svg width="640" height="500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" desc="description">
    <path desc="l 0 p 0" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" opacity="0.0" d="M 0.5 0.0 L 640.0 0.5 L 639.5 500.0 L 0.0 499.5 L 0.5 0.0 Z"/>
    <path desc="l 9 p 0" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" opacity="0.8117647058823529" d="M 235.5 109.0 L 238.0 109.5 L 235.5 110.0 L 235.5 109.0 Z"/>
    <!-- ... -->
    <path desc="l 15 p 64" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" opacity="0.34509803921568627" d="M 303.5 294.0 L 304.0 296.5 L 303.0 296.5 L 303.5 294.0 Z"/>
    <path desc="l 7 p 21" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-width="1" opacity="0.596078431372549" d="M 306.5 304.0 L 308.5 307.0 L 306.5 304.0 Z"/>
</svg>
```

To glyph element in SVG font element like below:

```
<glyph glyph-name="A" unicode="A" d="M60 0h-60v2048h60v-2048z" />
```

With the usage of Java. How to do that?